# Mock a service provider - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, mocking

I am using a service provider in a specific controller, i registered the provider and resolved it successfully.

But the test i used to run by mocking the actual classes are not working any more.

I resolve the service in my controller using app():

```
$cart = app()->make('Cart');
```

This is how i used to mock it before switching to a service provider:

```
$this->cart = $this->createMock(Cart::class);
```

Now if i want to mock it, i am doing something like this:

```
$this->createMock(app()->make('Cart'));
```

And the test fails with the error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator::getMock() must be a array or string
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have similar problem during testing my custom service provider. I created testing trait to mock my service provider.

As you can see I am re-declaring `singleton` for my Firebase service provider and later using `use FirebaseProvider` in my tests-cases.

```
// FirebaseServiceProvider

namespace App\Providers;

use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory as FirebaseFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class FirebaseServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    ...

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Firebase::class, function() {
            return (new FirebaseFactory())
                ->withServiceAccount(ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(env('FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT')))
                ->create();
        });

        $this->app->alias(Firebase::class, 'firebase');
    }
}
```

---

```
// In ./tests/FirebaseProvider.php

namespace Tests;

use Kreait\Firebase;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri;
use Firebase\Auth\Token\Handler;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

trait FirebaseProvider
{

    public function mockFirebaseServiceProvider()
    {
        $serviceAccountMock = $this->createMock(ServiceAccount::class);

        $serviceAccountMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getProjectId')
            ->willReturn('project');

        $serviceAccountMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getClientId')
            ->willReturn('client');

        $serviceAccountMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getClientEmail')
            ->willReturn('client@email.tld');

        $serviceAccountMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getPrivateKey')
            ->willReturn('some private key');

        uopz_flags(Handler::class, null, 0); // hack: removes `final` keyword so we can mock-it
        $tokenHandlerMock = $this->createMock(Handler::class);

        $tokenHandlerMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('createCustomToken')
            ->willReturn(new \Lcobucci\JWT\Token());

        $this->app->singleton(Firebase::class, function () {
            return $this->createMock(Firebase::class);
        });
    }

}
```

---

```
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    ....

    protected function setUpTraits()
    {
        parent::setUpTraits();

        $uses = array_flip(class_uses_recursive(static::class));

        if (isset($uses[FirebaseProvider::class])) {
            $this->mockFirebaseServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}
```